# fetch associated Array in laravel/php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I m getting following response from a third party api using php. I want to retrieve "data" named key value. In simple words, I want to retrieve value of "#data". I have no idea why # sign is used with "data" named key.

```
array:1[
    dataInfo: DataPartInfo {
         #data: b"""
    }
]
```

Comment: What is `DataPartInfo`? Is that an object class?

Comment: Use `->{"#data"}` to access object properties with special characters.

Comment: It's likely that the API library provides accessors so you don't have to deal with this.

Comment: yes. I also retrieve that object by converting it into array. but I have no idea how to fetch key that has  # sign

Comment: If it's an array use `["#data"]`

Comment: There's nothing special about `#` in associative array indexes.

Comment: can you please share your code to call the third party api,